# In C++ how to define a list of list or list of stacks as Java does?

Tags: c++

For example, I tried the following ways. It did not work.

```
std::list<std::list> lists;
std::list<std::stack> stacks;
```

Comment: Please note that although this is a simple question and we already know the answer, "it did not work" is not a description that will yield any good answers once you ask more difficult questions. You need to include any errors, or expected and actual input and output.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how Java does it, but a list of lists of something is:

```
std::list< std::list<int> > listOfListOfIntegers;
```

The same goes for stack.

```
std::list< std::stack<int> > listOfStacksOfIntegers;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
std::list<int> list1;
std::list<int> list2;

std::list<std::list<int>> list_of_lists;
list_of_lists.push_back(list1);
list_of_lists.push_back(list2);
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a list of `int`, you use:

```
std::list<int> iList;
```

To create a list of list of `int`, you use:

```
std::list<std::list<int> > iListList;
```

To create a stack of `int`, you use:

```
std::stack<int> iStack;
```

To create a list of stack of `int`, you use:

```
std::list<std::stack<int> > iStackList;
```

Comment: Typo: ')' should be '>'

Comment: The spaces between the angled brackets are unnecessary in C++11.

Comment: @Rapptz That is true. Since the question was tagged `c++` and not `c++11`, I chose to add the extra spaces.